# how to implement Imrotate of Matlab in Opencv?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

for rotation in Opencv, i used following code:

```
Mat rotate(Mat src, double angle)
{
    Mat dst;
    Point2f pt(src.cols/2., src.rows/2.);    
    Mat r = getRotationMatrix2D(pt, angle, 1.0);
    warpAffine(src, dst, r, Size(src.cols, src.rows));
    return dst;
}
```

and in matlab i used:

```
im = imrotate(img, angle, 'bilinear', 'crop');
```

but results not equivalent.
how to fix that or implement imrotate of matlab in c++?

Comment: Adding example images (e.g. "source", "opencv version", "matlab version") would be helpful, since some people may not know what result does your code or Matlab produce.

Comment: Can you show the starting image, and the ones produced by Matlab and OpenCV?

Comment: I  want to result been exactly same. i use min square error and compare pixel to pixel. Matlab use a mex file, how to find matlab mex file?

Answer (score 0):

i got this code around 1 year ago. I do not remember where i got this. So i do not take any credit of this code. But i modified this code little.
The result is not exactly match with matlab result. But it is good enough to use.

```
cv::Mat imRotate(const cv::Mat source, double angle) {
    cv::Mat dst;
    // Special Cases
    if (std::fmod(angle, 360.0) == 0.0)
        dst = source;
    else{
        cv::Point2f center(source.cols / 2.0F, source.rows / 2.0F);
        cv::Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
        // determine bounding rectangle
        cv::Rect bbox = cv::RotatedRect(center, source.size(), angle).boundingRect();
        // adjust transformation matrix
        rot.at<double>(0, 2) += bbox.width / 2.0 - center.x;
        rot.at<double>(1, 2) += bbox.height / 2.0 - center.y;
        cv::warpAffine(source, dst, rot, bbox.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    }
    return dst;
}
```