# how to replicate matlab's imrotate in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Edit: Added the function code for matlabImrotate.

I need to translate code from matlab that uses this function.
some of the times it appears like this: `imrotate(double(im), d, 'bilinear','crop');`.
At other times it appears like this: `imrotate(im_mask, rotation_angle, 'crop');`
I tried to use the answer in [how to implement Imrotate of Matlab in Opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715363/how-to-implement-imrotate-of-matlab-in-opencv) , but got different results.

For example, by using the code from this link inside a function:

```
bool matlabImrotate(Mat& src, double angle, int interpolationMethod, Mat& dst)
{
    // src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715363/how-to-implement-imrotate-of-matlab-in-opencv
    try
    {
        // Special Cases
        if (fmod(angle, 360.0) == 0.0)
            dst = src;

        else {
            Point2f center(src.cols / 2.0F, src.rows / 2.0F);
            Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);

            // determine bounding rectangle
            Rect bbox = RotatedRect(center, src.size(), angle).boundingRect();

            // adjust transformation matrix

            //rot.at<double>(0, 2) += bbox.width / 2.0 - center.x;
            //rot.at<double>(1, 2) += bbox.height / 2.0 - center.y;

            warpAffine(src, dst, rot, bbox.size(), interpolationMethod);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Error in matlabImrotate - " << e.what() << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the following code:

```
double data[9]{
    0, 0, 3,
    4, 5, 0,
    0, 0, 9 };
Mat A = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, data);
matlabImrotate(A, -5, INTER_LINEAR, A);
cout << "A:" << endl;
cout << A << endl;
cout << endl;
```

I got the result:

```
A:
[0.4375, 0.3046875, 2.54296875, 0.328125, 0, 0;
 3.390625, 4.8134765625, 0.2421875, 0.0234375, 0, 0;
 0, 0.2724609375, 8.4462890625, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0.4921875, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

instead of matlab's:

```
A =

    1.2127    0.3141    1.2084
    2.5963    5.0000    1.2278
         0    3.2512    3.6252
```

Comment: https://learnopencv.com/image-rotation-and-translation-using-opencv/#image-rotation

Comment: please post here the code you are using.

Comment: Added the code to the question.

Comment: Also the MATLAB one, please

Comment: Of course it does not work, you are not using all the code, you removed the code that makes it rotate around the center (`rot.at ...`)

Comment: Even with those two lines, the output for some reason is a 6x6 matrix, when the input was 3x3.

Comment: that's because (1) you need to rotate around the image center (2) matlab's output is the same size as the input... so why do you try to enlarge the output? if you do that, you have to modify the affine transformation matrix to shift into the new center of the output