# How to imRotate with OpenCV, C++, and get the exact same result?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I tried everything available here related to this problem, but none gave me the exact same results, so I'd like to know if there exist one? and if so, how can I achieve it?

Let's talk about a simple example and hopefully find a way to get the same result in Matlab as well as in OpenCV:

Matlab:

```
test = [ 10 20 10 ; 20 10 10 ; 30 30 30]
im_rot = imrotate(double(test), -45, 'bilinear', 'crop');
```

Result:

```
im_rot =

   11.7157   14.1421   11.7157
   26.2132   10.0000   12.0711
   17.5736   24.1421    5.8579
```

OpenCV:

```
double data[9]{ 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30 };
Mat test = Mat(Size(3, 3), CV_64F, data);
```

What lines of code can get the exact same result as the one above?

Edit:
Tried the following:

```
void matlabImrotate(Mat& src, double angle, int interpolationMethod, Mat& dst)
{
    // src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715363/how-to-implement-imrotate-of-matlab-in-opencv
    try
    {
        
        // Special Cases
        if (fmod(angle, 360.0) == 0.0)
            dst = src;

        else {
            Point2f center(src.cols / 2.0F, src.rows / 2.0F);
            Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);

            cout << "center: " << center << endl;

            // determine bounding rectangle
            Rect bbox = RotatedRect(center, src.size(), angle).boundingRect();
        
            // adjust transformation matrix
        //  cout << "bbox.size: " << bbox.size() << endl;

            rot.at<double>(0, 2) += ((bbox.width ) / 2.0 - center.x );
            rot.at<double>(1, 2) += ((bbox.height ) / 2.0 - center.y );
        

            warpAffine(src, dst, rot, bbox.size(), interpolationMethod);
        }
    }
}
matlabImrotate(test, -45, INTER_LINEAR, res);
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1.40625, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 6.6796875, 11.69921875, 6.6796875, 0;
 0, 8.7890625, 24.53125, 13.41796875, 14.53125, 2.9296875;
 0, 2.8125, 23.4375, 20, 7.8125, 0.9375;
 0, 0, 2.8125, 18.310546875, 1.875, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0.263671875, 0, 0]
```

Also tried:

```
void matlabImrotate2(Mat& src, double angle, int interpolationMethod, Mat& dst, int border=0)
{
    // src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870089/how-to-imrotate-with-opencv-2-4-3
    Mat bordered_source;
    int top, bottom, left, right;
    top = bottom = left = right = border;
    copyMakeBorder(src, bordered_source, top, bottom, left, right, BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar());
    Point2f src_center(bordered_source.cols / 2.0F, bordered_source.rows / 2.0F);
    Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center , angle, 1.0);
    warpAffine(bordered_source, dst, rot_mat, bordered_source.size());
    return true;
}
matlabImrotate2(test, -45, INTER_LINEAR, res);
```

Result:

```
[9.375, 17.28515625, 17.28515625;
 23.4375, 21.09375, 11.09375;
 2.8125, 23.4375, 15.625]
```

Comment: Please show the ways you've tried, and their results

Comment: Added what I tried and the results in edit

Comment: your asking for "exact same results" makes me worry that you *might* not be satisfied by any answer. what are your criteria for satisfaction? -- what became of the *previous questions* you asked, like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72814822/how-to-replicate-matlabs-imrotate-in-opencv-c

Comment: your calculation for the center is wrong. the center is `(w-1)/2, (h-1)/2` and the dsize for warpAffine should be the input size, because your matlab call doesn't adjust the output either.

Comment: `M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center=(1,1), angle=-45, scale=1); cv.warpAffine(im, M, (3, 3), cv.INTER_LINEAR)`, that comes as close as OpenCV can. it uses 5-bit fixed point calculations. if you demand more, you need to look for other solutions.

Comment: @OriHirshfeld You may try using IPP function `ippiWarpAffineLinear_64f_C1R` (instead of using OpenCV). As far as I recall the IPP results are very close to MATLAB (but I never tried the double precision version).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This is sure good enough for me, thank you!